# The state sometimes doesn't updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So I made a project with React Native and Firebase.

My page will be like these:
[image]

Here are the structure of my Firebase DB:

```
appModels
 - profile
 - - KRhpx9jflO3eB2L6-bY
 - - - email: "yo1238@gmail.com"
 - - - house_id: "H1AuHfu3"
 - - - name: "yoyoyo"
 - - - phone: "02191239821"
 - - KRi_3InnKP2S8jYYBWs
 - - - email: "joe123@gmail.com"
 - - - house_id: "rJ23rB_n"
 - - - name: "jojojo"
 - - - phone: "09128391273"
```

Here are my codes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'React';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import styles from '../../styles';
import { firebaseApp, profilesRef } from '../authentication';


module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return({
      email: '',
      phone: '-',
      name: '-',
      houseID: '-'
    })
  },


  componentDidMount(){
    let user = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;

    this.setState({email: user.email})
    this.listenForItems(user, profilesRef); 
  },


  listenForItems(user, profilesRef){
    profilesRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      let contents = [];

      profilesRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.email).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(data => {
          contents.push({
            name: data.val().name,
            phone: data.val().phone,
            house_id: data.val().house_id
          })
        })
      });

      if (contents.length !== 0) {
        this.setState({
          phone: contents[0].phone,
          name: contents[0].name,
          houseID: contents[0].house_id
        })
      }
    })
  },

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={[styles.bodyAccount]}>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount1}>{this.state.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount2}>name</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount1}>{this.state.email}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount2}>email</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount1}>{this.state.phone}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount2}>phone</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount1}>{this.state.houseID}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textAccount2}>House ID</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

})
```

The main idea behind my code was, everytime user enter the page, the code will be running and do query in **profile** child in my firebase who `email == user.email` from authentication, get all values (name, phone, house_id), and update the state.
But sometimes when I debug my program via simulator, the state doesn't updated.

Can you guys help me to fix this issues and tell me what is going on here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: One thing that jumps out to me, but doesn't look like a core issue is that `accountsRef` is always undefined

Comment: ah, already edit that parts. see again my code mate